# Is there any way to call function in react-simple-chatbot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatbot

```
import ChatBot from "react-simple-chatbot";
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const useTimetable = async (grade, room) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    let today = new Date();
    let year = today.getFullYear();
    let month = today.getMonth() + 1;
    let date = today.getDate();

    const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

    const link =
      "https://open.neis.go.kr/hub/hisTimetable?Type=&Key=" +
      { api_key } +
      "&ATPT_OFCDC_SC_CODE=D10&SD_SCHUL_CODE=7240082&GRADE={grade}&AY=2023&CLASS_NM={room}&TI_FROM_YMD=" +
      year +
      month +
      date +
      "&TI_TO_YMD=" +
      year +
      month +
      date;
    const res = await fetch(link).then((res) => res.json());
    console.log(res.mealServiceDietInfo[1].row);
    setData(res.mealServiceDietInfo[1].row);
  };

  // const useDiet = async () => {
  //   const [data2, setData2] = useState([]);
  //   let today = new Date();
  //   let year = today.getFullYear();
  //   let month = today.getMonth() + 1;
  //   let date = today.getDate();

  //   const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

  //   const link =
  //     "https://open.neis.go.kr/hub/mealServiceDietInfo?MLSV_YMD=" +
  //     year.toString() +
  //     month.toString().padStart(2, "0") +
  //     date.toString().padStart(2, "0") +
  //     "&Type=json&pIndex=1&pSize=100&ATPT_OFCDC_SC_CODE=D10&SD_SCHUL_CODE=7240082";
  //   const res = await fetch(link).then((res) => res.json());
  //   console.log(res.hisTimetable[1].row);
  //   setData2(res.hisTimetable[1].row);
  //   return data2;
  // };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="chatbot">
        <ChatBot
          steps={[
            {
              id: "1",
              message: "Welcome. school information service.",
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              id: "2",
              message: "press start button to get information.",
              trigger: "3",
            },
            {
              id: "3",
              options: [{ value: 1, label: "start", trigger: "4" }],
            },
            {
              id: "4",
              options: [
                { value: 1, label: "Today's timetable", trigger: "5" },
                { value: 1, label: "Today's diet", trigger: "5" },
              ],
            },
            {
              id: "5",
              message: "select your grade.",
              trigger: "6",
            },
            {
              id: "6",
              options: [
                { value: 1, label: "1", trigger: "7" },
                { value: 1, label: "2", trigger: "7" },
                { value: 1, label: "3", trigger: "7" },
              ],
            },
            {
              id: "7",
              message: "select your class.",
              trigger: "8",
            },
            {
              id: "8",
              options: [
                { value: 1, label: "1", trigger: "9" },
                { value: 1, label: "2", trigger: "10" },
                { value: 1, label: "3", trigger: "11" },
                { value: 1, label: "4", trigger: "12" },
                { value: 1, label: "5", trigger: "13" },
                { value: 1, label: "6", trigger: "14" },
                { value: 1, label: "7", trigger: "15" },
                { value: 1, label: "8", trigger: "16" },
                { value: 1, label: "9", trigger: "17" },
              ],
            },
            // {
            //1-1
            //   id: "9",
            //   message: "timetable of today",
            //   component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 1)}</div>,
            //   trigger: "2",
            // },
            {
              //1-1
              id: "9",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 1)}</div>,
              trigger: "1",
            },
            {
              //1-2
              id: "10",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 2)}</div>,
              trigger: "1",
            },
            {
              //1-3
              id: "11",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 3)}</div>,
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              //1-4
              id: "12",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 4)}</div>,
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              //1-5
              id: "13",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 5)}</div>,
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              //1-6
              id: "14",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 6)}</div>,
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              //1-7
              id: "15",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 7)}</div>,
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              //1-8
              id: "16",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 8)}</div>,
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              //1-9
              id: "17",
              message: "timetable of today",
              component: <div>{useTimetable(1, 9)}</div>,
              trigger: "2",
            },
            {
              id: "9",
              message: "select your grade.",
            },
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I want to call a function in react-simple-chatbot.
I choose react-simple-chatbot because there are more documents in google, and the only post in Korean used Typescript. So, react-simple-chatbot is the only way for me to make chatbot in react.
I tried to call function in react-simple-chatbot, but I failed all the ways tried. Is it impossible to call a function in react-simple-chatbot?